# Private roads to Bristol from Leeds

Tags: uk, road-trips

We are going to travel from Leeds to Bristol by Road next week. When checking in google maps, i see that "Continue onto A42
Parts of this road may be closed at certain times or on certain days"

How can i find more details on these private roads? whether it is accessible to public?

Comment: The A42 is a major trunk road not a private road AFAIK https://www.sabre-roads.org.uk/wiki/index.php?title=A42, it’s likely to be closed for eg road repairs at certain times, or an accident (but then so is any road). Try searching A42 closures https://www.trafficengland.com/

Comment: If you are using SatNav, then the ones with 'live updates' will route you around any road closures. The A42 is not a private road.

Comment: This is *not* google maps warning you about private roads - that would be "This route has restricted usage or includes private roads". This warning is exactly what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UK reports of road closures at [Daily closures](https://nationalhighways.co.uk/travel-updates/road-closure-report/), and seemed to be presented a week at a time.  Currently none are listed for the A42, but that could change at a later date.

I did note that google maps shows some congestion around Lount, which could be indicative of current roadworks (nut not a closure)

WetherVane pointed out a different site, but the item there only appears to affect northbound travel.

But given that the UK is criss-crossed by all manner of roads, even if you don't know ahead of time about a closure, then you'll simply be diverted around the road works.

Comment: [This site](https://www.trafficdelays.co.uk/link-road-from-m1-j23a-a42-to-a453-northbound-northbound-road-works-leicestershire-2/) has *Road Affected: A42. Description of incident: Location : The junction of the A42 and the M1 J23A. Reason : Roadside drains works are planned. Status : Pending. Schedule : From 20:00 on 29 July 2022 to 06:00 on 30 July 2022. Lanes Closed : All lanes will be closed.*

Comment: @WeatherVane That closure would only appear to affect the northbound M1 and A42 ramps to the A453, and not the A42 to the M1, and the OP is traveling in the opposite direction anyway.